# Когда создается объект HttpSession?

Tags: java, servlet, сессия

В сервлете есть метод:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println(req.getSession(false));
    req.getRequestDispatcher(indexPage).forward(req, resp);
}
```

При использовании `apache-tomcat-8.5.15` при первом обращении получается следующий лог:

```
null
null
org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@5e21a333
```

Я всегда думал что существует возможность управлять процессом создания сессии при помощи `getSession(true/false)`. Но выходит что сессия создается вне зависимости от моего желания? Так как же мне обеспечить что бы сессия не создавалась до тех пор, пока я сам не скажу `getSession(true)`? Хоть я `false` параметром и выставил, а все равно получил ее создание...

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться что произошло. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего в вашем приложении использовался JSP. По умолчанию сессия создается при обращении к произвольной JSP странице, если это в явном виде не отключено специальной директивой `<%@ page session="false" %>`

В остальном вы правы `req.getSession(false)` не приводит к созданию сессии, если она не была создана до этого.